# Найти цикл в неориентированном графе

Tags: java, алгоритм, циклы, графы

Если в иcходном графе нет цикла, то выведите «NO». Иначе, в первой строке выведите «YES», во второй строке выведите число k — количество вершин в цикле, а в третьей строке выведите k различных чисел — номера вершин, которые принадлежат циклу в порядке обхода (обход можно начинать с любой вершины цикла). Если циклов несколько, то выведите любой.

Подскажите, как это сделать? Никак не могу разобраться. Ниже мой код.

Формат ввода:

3

0 1 1

1 0 1

1 1 0

Формат вывода:

YES

3

3 2 1

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main

{

    static int g[][], used[];
    static ArrayList co = new ArrayList();

    static int n,k;
    static String flag;

    static void dfs(int v)

    {

        used[v] = 1;
        co.add(v);

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if (g[v][i] == 1) {

                if (used[i] == 1) {
                    flag = "YES";
                } else if (used[i] == 0) {
                    dfs(i);
                }

            }


            used[v] = 2;
        }
        k+=1;

    }



    public static void main(String[] args)

    {

        Scanner con = new Scanner(System.in);

        n = con.nextInt();

        g = new int[n+1][n+1];

        used = new int[n+1];



        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {

            for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            {
                g[i][j] = con.nextInt();
            }
        }



        flag = "NO";

        for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            if(used[i] ==0) {
                dfs(i);

                if (k > 0)
                {
                    i = n;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(flag);
        if (flag != "NO")
        {
            System.out.println(k);
            for(int i=0;i<co.size();i++)
            {
                System.out.print(co.get(i)+" ");
            }
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: В вашем вопросе отсутвует вопрос. Опишите конкретную проблему, с которой вам не справиться.

Comment: Почему-то программа выдает неверный ответ. Не могу найти ошибку в коде, которая к этому приводит.

Comment: `if (used[i] == 1) {` а вы уверены что тут равно 1, а не `!= 0` должно быть?

Comment: даже если я это меняю. программа все равно не проходит тесты